# Return type generic

Tags: java, generics

I am learning to use generics in java and I need the following function (in a class with a generic attribute  to work:

```
public T evaluate() {
    if (arg.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
        return !arg.getValue();
    } else if (arg.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
        return -arg.getValue();
    }
}
```

The class has an attribute arg of type Expression. arg.getValue returns a variable of type T. The function evaluate should return the logic negation of arg.getValue if T is a boolean and -arg.getValue if T is an Integer. It does not compile, because the - and ! operators "cannot be applied to T".

Abother option would be to implement the following idea:

```
public T evaluate() {
    if (arg.getValue() instanceof Boolean) {
        Boolean b = (Boolean) arg.getValue();
        Boolean r = new Boolean(!b);
        return r;
    } else if (arg.getValue() instanceof Integer) {
        Integer i = (Integer) arg.getValue();
        Integer r = -i;
        return r;
    }
}
```

But that way the return does not work: "incopatible types Required: T Found:java.lang.Boolean/Integer"

Any Ideas?

Comment: What's `arg`? and why `-`?

Comment: `public <T> T evaluate() {}`

Comment: `public <T> T negate(T arg){}`

Comment: `-((Integer)arg.getValue());`

Comment: @HadiJ i suppose this is in a class <T>

Comment: Whichever class that `arg` is should define a `negateValue()` method (e.g. `public T negateValue()`).

Comment: `new Boolean(!b)` is redundant, as Java supports autoboxing: `Boolean r = !b`

Answer (score 6):

That's not how it works. A generic type doesn't mean "I don't know what I'll return, we'll see depending on what I get, which might be anything from an implementation-dependent list". The `T` type might be variable, but only at implementation time - at run time, it is fixed and either `Boolean` or `Integer`.

So what you can do is

```
public interface Inverter<T> {
    // variable return type, depending on argument
    T invert(T toInvert);
}
```

with the implementations

```
class IntegerInverter implements Inverter<Integer> {
    // return type is fixed to integer
    Integer invert(Integer toInvert) {
        return -toInvert.intValue();
    }
}

class BooleanInverter implements Inverter<Boolean> {
    // return type is fixed to boolean
    Boolean invert(Boolean toInvert) {
        return !toInvert.booleanValue();
    }
}
```

Note that it's probably best to reuse existing interfaces, eg

```
UnaryOperator<Integer> intInverter = i -> -i.intValue();
UnaryOperator<Boolean> boolInverter = b -> !b.booleanValue();
```

EDIT:
The suggestion by @Twometer would result in something like

```
class Inverters {
    public static UnaryOperator<Integer> integerInverter() {
        return i -> -i.intValue();
    }
    public static UnaryOperator<Boolean> boolInverter() {
        return b -> !b.booleanValue();
    }

    // and maybe even this, but this will still require a cast
    // at the client
    public static <T> UnaryOperator<?> inverter(Class<T> clazz) {
        if (clazz == Integer.class) {
            return integerInverter();
        } else if (clazz == Boolean.class) {
            return boolInverter();
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Cannot create inverter for class %s", clazz));
    }
}
```

This way you have a central way of getting the inverters you need; this way you're sure they'll be reused. Also, you can cache the created lambdas without having to change client code.

Comment: And then make a factory based on the input class type

Comment: @Twometer I added a factory method collection class to the answer.

Comment: Nice, I have just seen it.

Answer (score 1):

Generics will only help if two classes that you want to differentiate between have a (useful) common superclass. However the first common superclass of `Boolean` and `Integer` is `Object`, which is not useful.

If your objective is to learn generics, I suggest using *e.g.* `Integer` and `Double` which both do have a common subclass `Number`, so you can define `T` as `T extends Number`

If your objective is exactly as your example, then [edit] you can follow @daniu's answer.